# Sails.js: applying session and token authentication policies simultaniously

Tags: session, authentication, merge, sails.js, token

I am developing an application with sails.js. For the web application I use session authentication with passport. Now I also need to make my server accessibe from a mobile application, which requires token authentication. My question is the following: how can I define the policies so that sails accept SessionAuth or TokenAuth  for certain routes?

Comment: This should be sort of straightforward - can you be more specific about what's confusing you? Do you know generally how to use sails policies? Do you know how to do session and token auth separately?

Comment: I know that if I write for example `edit : ['pol1', 'pol2']` pol1 AND pol2 are applied, but I want pol1  OR pol2 to be applied

Comment: Basically my doubt is how to edit config/policies.js in order to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way sails handles policies, they are all applied one after another using AND logic. There is no way to combine them logically in other ways, like OR or more complicated combinations.

In your case, I would expect it would be fairly easy to write a third policy that handles the "SessionAuth or TokenAuth" all in one policy. Say you have existing `SessionAuth.js` and `TokenAuth.js` policies that look like this:

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isSessionAuthorized()) {
        return next();
    }
    // handle rejected request
};
```

, and,

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isTokenAuthorized()) {
        return next();
    }
    // handle rejected request
};
```

Then you just create a third policy called `SessionOrTokenAuth.js`:

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isSessionAuthorized() || req.isTokenAuthorized()) {
        return next();
    }
    // handle rejected request
};
```

Then apply the newly created policy to the desired controller endpoints in `/config/policies.js`:

```
SomeController: {
    '*': true,
    'sessionOnlyEndpoint': ['SessionAuth'],
    'tokenOnlyEndpoint': ['TokenAuth'],
    'anyAuthEndpoint': ['SessionOrTokenAuth'],
}
```

The actual checks are likely a touch more complicated, but probably not by much. Hope this helps.